# re.split and delimiter to result

Tags: python, regex

How i can include delimetr to `re.split` result?

For example, i have text

```
Bla bla lbaa dsad asd as. Asd qe as!  ASDadf asd! Dsss dwq. Dkmef?
```

RegExr

```
re.split('\s*([\.!\?]+)\s*', data)
```

And `re.split` return this

```
['Bla bla lbaa dsad asd as', '.', 'Asd qe as', '!', 'ASDadf asd', '!', 'Dsss dwq', '.', 'Dkmef', '?', '']
```

While i want this

```
['Bla bla lbaa dsad asd as.', 'Asd qe as!', 'ASDadf asd!', 'Dsss dwq.']
```

How i can do it without spikes?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try splitting by whitespace preceded by punctuaction:

```
In [9]: re.split(r'(?<=[\.!\?])\s+', data)
Out[9]:
['Bla bla lbaa dsad asd as.',
 'Asd qe as!',
 ' ASDadf asd!',
 'Dsss dwq.',
 'Dkmef?']
```

Explanation from the [documentation for the re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `(?<=...)`
>
> Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for `...`
>   that ends at the current position. This is called a positive lookbehind
>   assertion. `(?<=abc)def` will find a match in `abcdef`, since the lookbehind will
>   back up 3 characters and check if the contained pattern matches. The
>   contained pattern must only match strings of some fixed length, meaning that
>   `abc` or `a|b` are allowed, but `a*` and `a{3,4}` are not.

Comment: Нормалды все :) В принципе, так тоже можно сделать. Спасибо, Павел.

Comment: And now in English, for the rest of us ;)